# Splitting a tuple of bags into multiple tuples using regex_extarct_all in pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have my input string as

```
{(100),(200),(300)}
```

and I want to split them into different columns using `regex_extract_all`.

I have used `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(data,'[^{(,)}]+')` and I am getting an error saying:

```
Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a tuple of bags, you can't use it as a chararray field - thus you can't use REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL with it. If you want to split it into multiple tuples, use the function BagToTuple and FLATTEN.

e.g.:

```
...
a = load '/tmp/1.txt';
b = group a by $0;
c = foreach b generate group, FLATTEN(BagToTuple(a.$1));
...
```

Comment: But using FLATTEN gives me the output in different rows as 100 in 1st row, 200 in 2nd row and 300 in 3rd row

Comment: I thought that you wanted it in multiple tuples (i.e. multiple rows). Is the bag in a fixed size? Do you know how many fields you'd like to transform the bag into? What would you do with the fields?

Comment: yes the bag is in fixed size. i want the bag to be in 3 columns and dump them.

Comment: can you post your entire script? if it's in your input file, you can load it as a chararray and extract the individual fields you'd like (REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL will give you a bag back anyway)

Comment: top3 = FOREACH GroupedDataSet{ sorted = ORDER GroupedData BY TotSESTimePerURl DESC; lim = LIMIT sorted 3; GENERATE FLATTEN(group), lim.CATEGORYCODE, lim.TotSESTimePerURl; }; I am taking out the top3 based on the time spent.The top3::CATEGORYCODE gives me {(100),(200),(300)} which i want in 3 columns

Comment: ok, so try BagToTuple - it's a builtin function that returns a tuple of fields for a bag which you can flatten to get the fields as part of your outer bag. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToTuple.java

Comment: I had tried this already but it gives me an error saying "ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Expecting a bag of tuples: {()}" although i am giving {(100),(200),(300)}  as the input.